# Segue type to be used for a user registration process - iOS 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, rubymotion

This is my first ios app & I have a user registration process which is separated out into 3 screens. The first screen has user to enter his mobile number, the second screen asks him select his location & the third screen asks him to enter his birthday and a few other details.

So in total, there are totally 3 controllers which I have used.

1) mobile_number_controller.rb
2) location_controller.rb
3) miscellaneous_details_controller.rb

Each detail the user enters is validated and is stored into the NSUserDefaults. If the validation fails then the user is not allowed to move to the next screen. Also, once the user enters his details correctly, then the user does not have a back button to go back to the previous screen as well.

I would like to know which is the type of segue to be used here. Should I embed these controllers in a navigation controller and use a push segue, or should I be using a modal segue?

**Update regarding the chain of controllers.**

I don't intend to take the user back to any presenting controller at any stage. Also, in most code I have read till now, for **modal segues**, I have seen the presented controller being dismissed or there's an unwind segue to go back to the presented controller. I am a bit confused on what to do with these presented controller here before presenting the next controller in the series?

Also, as I mentioned that I store whatever data has been entered by the user in NSUserDefaults, theres no need for the presenting controller to know about the data entered in the presented controller. Hence I don't feel the need for an unwind segue( like in the 'new contacts' application).

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: +1 @herrm for using navigation controller , imho it provides more control with less boilerplate. code as compared to modal presenting every controller. And in your case if going back is not an option just remove the back bar button from all the navigation item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a series of modal segues (presented view controller). This is not a "user can go forward and back among views" situation: *you* are in total control of what the user sees. It is perfectly legal to present a view controller on top of a presented view controller. Moreover, it is simple to control how far back you take the user, e.g. go back all the way (dismissing all the views), if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Just as a parallel case, I have an app with an in-app purchase and the interaction ("are you interested in more info about this in-app purchase?" "Okay, here's the info: would you like to buy it?") is a sequence of presented view controllers.

Comment: I dont intend to take the user back to any presenting controller at any stage. Also, I in most code I have read till now, I have seen the presented controller being dismissed or theres an unwind segue to go back to the presented controller. I am a bit confused on what to do with these presented controller here before presenting the next controller in the series?

Comment: Could you be more specific? How can you not go back? What if the user wants to cancel from registration? And at some point you are going to have to show a screen that is not one of the registration screens, right? Your real, main interface? What I'm suggesting is that everything is a series of presented view controllers on top of that, and once registration is done, you whip them all away. The user may not experience it that way; it's just an architecture.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you "do" anything before presenting the next view controller. Just keep presenting the next view controller. There is no need to dismiss-then-present, dismiss-then-present. That's just ugly.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Was a bit confused on dismissing the presented controllers. I will do the dismissal part once the registration process is over, right?

Comment: Yes, and at that point you may have a question about how to do that (esp. if you use an unwind segue, which can be tricky). But let's cross that bridge when we come to it. Also, don't worry about getting locked into an architecture; it's not that hard to change your mind later.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer a modal segue to present a navigation controller and push segues to connect the other view controllers. Similar to webapps a user perhaps want to step back to change previously entered information.